# ERROR: derefrencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a dish.h file where I wrote this typedef:

```
typedef struct dish_t* Dish;
```

Then I have a dish.c file where I defined my struct:

```
struct dish_t {
Type type;
char *name;
int sweetness;
int saltiness;
int sourness;
};
```

I wrote some unitests in the dish.c and they were fine but once I've moved them to a sepearate dish_test.c file I recived the following error:

"derefrencing pointer to incomplete type"

It accured once I tried to access a Dish instance like this:

```
    dish=dishCreate("soup",1,2,3,type,&error);
    int cmp=strcmp("soup",dish->name); // error accured here
```

Any ideas why it happanes?

Comment: why did you define the struct in a .c file? It should be in the .h file, so the dish_test.c has the definition.

Comment: I am *SURE* this is a duplicate... found it. One minute of looking at the "related" list (which you were presented with while *typing* your question, and could have checked yourself).

Voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the struct definition to the header file when it is used in more than one file.

If you want to keep it "private" you need two header files a public and a private one.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you moved your definition out where the test code can't see it.

`#include` does exactly that, it includes the file you give it. Before you moved the definition, the way the compiler should build the struct was visible, now it has no chance of knowing if or where the "name" element of the dish struct is.

Move the definition of your type back into the header or alternatively use accessor functions taking `Dish` instead of writing directly to the elements if you wish a more OO-like style.